# I Merge Two DataFrames in Pandas and Create a Single DataFrame From it but it is not able to sort Values from 2nd Dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City':['Kareli','Narsinghpur','Jabalpur','Gadarwara','Pipriya'],
    'Temperature':[23,45,67,12,34]
})
df
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hySYJ.png)
This is First DataFrame.

```
 df2 = pd.DataFrame({
'City':['Narsinghpur','Jabalpur','Pipriya','Kareli','Gadarwara'],
'Humidity':[15,23,30,45,34]
 })
 df2
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/830Hi.png) 
This is Second DataFrame.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df,df2,on='City')
df3
```

[Merged Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd3BJ.png) After Merging I am Not Get the values of "Humidity" Sorted According to 'City.

Plzz Check The Value of 'Humidity' for the City 'Gadarwara' in 2nd DataFrame which is 34 after merging it become 45

Comment: Where do you actually do a sort?

Comment: I am sorry but this site has rules on how to ask question. As a new user, you should read [ask]. Here you should not post images but simply show the dataframes as text in the question itself, and you failed to give the expected result.

Comment: After the merge, try doing `df=df.sort_values(['City'])`

Comment: I am Sorry for that u can see images @Serge Ballesta

Answer (score 0):

This is the output I get for `df3` when I run your code:

```
    City         Temperature  Humidity
0   Kareli       23           45
1   Narsinghpur  45           15
2   Jabalpur     67           23
3   Gadarwara    12           34
4   Pipriya      34           30
```

As you can see, everything is as it should be. I'm not sure why you get a different result. Try clearing the namespace and run the code again. Be sure to use the latest version of Pandas.